# Function with return and to show the value in the view

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp, how do I create a function that returns a value to me in the **Controller** and the value that returns to me can be shown in the view?

Thank you.

Comment: Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask a question on stackoverflow. You need to explain what you have done and what problem you are facing and also share your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can create a function in your controller that will return a value. For e.g

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function dashboard() {
        $value = $this->search();
        $this->set('value', $value);
    }

    public function search() {
     return "hello"
    }
}
```

On dashboard.ctp file you can directly access that variable like

```
<?php echo $value?>
```

Comment: I already made the attempt but it shows that error. I'm new to cakephp. Thank you-  "Controller actions can only return Cake\Http\Response or null".

Comment: @AndresFelipePinzonBaldion Can you please share your code because I have already tried this and it's working fine.

Comment: @AndresFelipePinzonBaldion I made an edit in my answer. Please check. You need to add above code in your controller not on ctp

Comment: I do not understand.
can you show me an example?
Look, I did this.
it's okay ?
public function search () {
         $ value = $ this-> search ();
         $ this-> set ('value', $ value);
         return "hello";
     }

Comment: Can you please share your Controller and view name on which you want to show the value?

Comment: that I add it in the controller, in the ctp I do not know what to put.

Comment: --- CONTROLLER ---
public function search () {
         $ value = $ this-> search ();
         $ this-> set ('value', $ value);
         return "hello";
     }

Comment: You can directly access that variable using it's name like <?php echo $value?>

Comment: THAT WAS WHAT I PUT ON THE CONTROLLER AS YOU SAID ME

Comment: Do I put that in the ctp?

Comment: nothing, I still did not srive put the two functions in the controller and call as you said and nothing. look
--- controller ---
  public function search () {
         return "hello";
     }

     public function dashboard () {
     $ value = $ this-> search ();
    // and then set it in your view like
     $ this-> set ('value', $ value);
  }


--- view ctp ----
<h1>
<? php
echo $ value
?>
</ h1>

Comment: Are you there? Sehdev

Comment: @AndresFelipePinzonBaldion: please check my answer again. I have made some changes for your understanding.